# Access Objects Image Size

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

Is there a way in Access 2016 to make the Access objects Icons smaller, I have a lot of objects in the database and the icons are very big.

Ideally like the picture on the right, I am sure that i am missing something simple, but not been in Access for a long time.  I have looked around in the access navigation options etc, but cant seem to find an option for this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click at a free space below that tables list (not directly on a table).
2. Click *"View By"*
3. Choose *"List"*.

And it looks exactly like your right screenshot.
By the way *"List"* is the default so you must somehow have changed it to *"Details"* previously.